# adding string value has different beahviour im python

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I am trying to calculate a date on basis of an input variable to determine an url string. For sure nothing new, but I wanted to do it on my own and I am wondering about the behavior:

Determining the variables:

```
year = '2020'
month = '12'
day = 12


daylist = []


for item in range(5):
    day = int(day) - 1
    if day == 0:
      day = 31
    daylist.append(day)

print(daylist)

for item in daylist:
  if item in range(0,10):
    newitem = str(0) + str(item)
    daylist.remove(item)
    daylist.append(newitem)

print(daylist)

OUtput is:
[11, 10, 9, 8, 7]
[11, 10, 8, '09', '07']
```

The second row should look like: `[11, 10, '08', '09', '07']`

Here is my question: The figure `8` does not add a zero. As you see it works well with `09` and `07`. I am a bit confused. Have any of you have an idea or can you reengineer the same problem?

Comment: What is the expected output and what is the input you are passing?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to modify a collection whilst iterating through it. This can yield surprising results.

Answer (score 0):

not sure to understand your question here... Where is the input on your code ?
Also for date questions in python, you should use the datetime module instead of tweaking your own stuff (always tricky to play with dates)...

Comment: Thank you for getting back. I dont know if datetime will meet my requirements. At the end the URL shoul look like this: http:/test.de/202012-10-lsxtradesyesterday.csv'. I am trying to concat strings and determine the date in between with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to replace your list like this:

```py
daylist = [item if item not in range(10) else ‘0’+str(item) for item in daylist]
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot for taking time but this not that what i was looking for.